# How to unit test search functionality?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, tdd

First off, i'm just new to unit testing or testing in general so i'm still wrapping my head around some concepts. Already got the basic of unit testing and I'm also currently learning about rxjs marble testing, so currently i'm stuck on how to test searching w/c functions the same way with the code in the documentation.

So Let's use the code from the tour of heroes in angular documentation

```
this.heroes$ = this.searchTerms.pipe(
  // wait 300ms after each keystroke before considering the term
  debounceTime(300),

  // ignore new term if same as previous term
  distinctUntilChanged(),

  // switch to new search observable each time the term changes
  switchMap((term: string) => this.heroService.searchHeroes(term)),
);
```

Here's my current test looks like

```
const searchResults$ = (inputs$: Observable<string>) =>
  inputs$.pipe(
    debounceTime(300),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    switchMap((term: string) => fakeHeroService.searchHeroes(term))
  );

  it('should return the correct results', () => {
    scheduler.run(helpers => {
      const { cold, hot, expectObservable } = helpers;

      // these are the search terms typed by user, observable
      // emitted by this.searchTerms
      const inputMarbles = '^-a 300ms b-c 300ms';

      // each emitted response by each service call
      const outputMarbles = '-- 300ms a-- 300ms c';

      // verify that service is called N times
      // verify that it's passed with certain argument per run


      searchServiceSpy = spyOn(heroService, 'searchHeroes').and.returnValue(
        cold(outputMarbles)
      );
      const source$ = hot(inputMarbles);

      const output$ = source$.pipe(searchResults$);

      expectObservable(output$).toBe(outputMarbles);

      /* expect(fakeSearchService.getMatches).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2); */
    });
  });
```

I just can't get it working.

Comment: I prefer cypress for all testing.  Might want to check it out.

Comment: @John Peter's isn't it just for e2e tests? Should I just skip unit test in this case?

Comment: Yes that's my suggestion because Cypress can cover all endpoint tests as well as intercept HTTPClient  requests (inbound or outbound) You can isolate the API covering all boundaries as well as the front end doing the same boundary testing. Anything else would have to be mocked from within, like take database down, or clear database entries that are dependent on app running.  Cypress has blurred the lines of legacy test definitions.

Comment: I've been stuck with this for days, so i might just do it cypress way if I can't find a solution

Comment: Do you have 20 minutes to try it out?  https://dev.to/jwp/angular-and-cypress-in-20-minutes-21be

Comment: It's just my opinion but I think the whole Karma/Jasmine spy gig is ridiculous.

Comment: Thanks. I have a basic knowledge with cypress but I'll definitely check out the article to improve my knowledge. I also got stuck with cypress when it comes to Google login since they don't allow redirects

Comment: Cypress is great. I'm even a cypress ambassador, and I do tons of training on it. But IMHO it's no replacement for unit tests. Testing things like making sure you have exactly 300ms of denounce isn't really feasible with cypress. You don't have that fine grained control over time. But lots of people eschew unit tests for just integration/e2e. But for me that's a mistake. Unit tests (especially when done with TDD) are not truly replaced by things like cypress.

Comment: @JosephEames in this case, is it advisable to test the debounceTime or just test that the service is called after debounce? It just occured to me that i'm just testing the rxjs operators one by one, i'm probably getting this wrong, i'm just testing for the sake of doing tests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest testing each part of the chain (debounce, disticnt, switchMap) in a separate test.

You can use [observer-spy](https://github.com/hirezio/observer-spy) with combination of `fakeAsync` for much easier tests.

For example, to test the `debounce` you can write something like this (the following code might not be complete, but this is just to illustrate the point) -

```
import {subscribeAndSpyOn} from '@hirez_io/observer-spy';

it('should debounce by 300 ms', fakeAsync(() => {

  // basically with "debounce" you only care if 2 triggers happened and enough time passed, 
  // the number of results should be 1...

  const observerSpy = subscribeAndSpyOn(serviceUnderTest.heroes$);
  serviceUnderTest.searchTerms.next();
  tick(100);
  serviceUnderTest.searchTerms.next();
  tick(300);
  expect(observerSpy.getValuesLength).toBe(1);

}));
```

And write similar tests for the others that uses the "just enough principle" to setup the conditions for other operators in the chain.

Comment: Shai's advice is something everyone should take. :)

Comment: Thanks, i think trying to wrap around my head with a lot of concepts got me confused that i got stucked that the only way to test this is using rxjs-marble testing. This one's i feel like easier in this case.